# php soap wsdl connection error

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I have been trying to connect to a web service which I previously had set up using a soap request in PHP, like so:

```
$client = new SoapClient($this->config->item('WSDL'));
$response = $client->Login(array('email' => $this->input->post('email'), 'password' => $this->input->post('password')));
```

this worked when the WSDL url ended in asmx?WSDL but now its a different url ending in .xml and it doesn't work...I keep getting the following error: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in..."

Can anyone help me please? It is hurting my head, thanks!

Comment: You might want to go back and accept some answers on your older questions to motivate people to care about this one :) http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

URL of WSDL can be ended with anything. Try to echo your WSDL URL and load it by browser.

```
$client = new SoapClient(exit($this->config->item('WSDL')));
```